# Configuration-Management in git

Tags: git, git-branch

I am not sure if configuration management is the right term for my problem.

At the moment we are using CVS with sub-modules. It's possible to check out a base version and add different other modules. Changing something in any sub-module is tracked (so you can make a `cvs status` in the root dir and get all changes in sub-modules and so on). I know that git has sub-modules, too, but on this page http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules#Starting-with-Submodules they mention that the sub-modules are not tracked from the root (I guess you have to make all the git commands in the subdir and can't do it in the root).

Is there any other possibility to use that sub-module concept like it is done in CVS?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are [git subtrees](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/05/alternatives-to-git-submodule-git-subtree/) those are managed by the root repository.

Some advantage over submodules (in your case):

- managed from main repository
- main still behaves like a regular repository for most cases
- no seperate cloning needed

but you have to adopt a different merging strategy and the responisbility not to mix root and subproject commits is totaly in your hands

Comment: This stuff is one of the weak points of git the choices are either subtrees or submodules and both are designed in a way that you only want to use them if there is realy no way around it...